# Can we ask questions about P90X? Or is just mentioning it the equivalent of spam?

Tags: discussion

P90X is a DVD-based workout system that is heavily advertised in the States in print media, sports radio, and infomericals. It presents a compelling 90-day exercise and diet regimen that results in impressive before and after photos. It is produced by company called Beachbody which specializes in these types of DVD-fitness workouts.

The downside is that there are some less savory aspects to the company such as the free coaching they offer which is appears to be a form of multi-level marketing.

That said, the system is also considered to be very effective. I'm doing it now and seeing results.

I would like to ask questions about it. But I'm not sure if it would be considered "spammy" because it is advertised and marketed so heavily in the states. What is the policy for these types of DVD-based workouts?

Comment: Quick explanation of what P90X is, and why it would be controversial?

Comment: P90x is just building on top of what traditional workouts are.

Comment: @kjy In what way? More specifically, what is different from a normal workout that could cause OP to question whether it's "spam"?

Comment: p90x just a mixing of doing push ups, pull ups in different forms.  a spam would be considered "need to drop x lb in one week" which is unrelistic based on p90x philosophy. in a more obvious way..."are the actors or actress on dvd hot or not?" is definately spammy lol

Comment: The main reason why p90x would be spammy is because the only "official" way to learn about it is to [buy their DVDs](http://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/p90x.do).

Comment: @eykanal that is absolutely not true.

Comment: @kjy112 - do you want to post some alternative source of information, then? I guess you could sign up for a workshop of theirs, but that's the same sort of deal. I'm not suggesting that it's a cult or anything, just that it's the way it is.

Comment: @eykanal i have done p90x and really it's just old traditional workout routines except they lined it up for you to follow.  Basic push ups, pull ups, lunges, jumping jacks and etc. its nothing "special." in fact, Tony Hornton states "Tony takes you back to basics—old-school style, like 2000 years back." just educating people the "buying is the relic" modern way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just stay on-topic and ask for questions that explain why or how things work and I don't see any problem with the topic per se.

Answer (score 6):

Just be very mindful about this issue: [Please avoid very broad, beginners questions during the beta](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/please-avoid-very-broad-beginners-questions-during-the-beta).

If you want to ask very *specific* questions about an exercise regimen, that should be okay. But if your question is, "Does this P90X diet work?" (for example), I would ask that you wait until this site has build up a better repository of *real* questions before asking.