# A proposal to allow non professionals to use this site

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As some of you know the StackOverflow.com site is for programmers who what to be more professional. There are lot's of simple questions there, as well as answers. I belive this was a great idea to allow ask **any** kind of questions about software development, because today one can find an answer(s) on **any** question.

However the fitness site strictly prohibits to ask newbie questions. The [FAQ](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) clearly states: `Fitness - Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes and trainers.` Thus, I see no possibility for ordinary people to became more professional in fitness using this site. As the result the site will never became any more popular than it is now, because most of the visitor are novice athletes and are seaching for simple answers.

I propose remove that line from FAQ and allow asking any fitness related questions.

I am aware of [this proposal](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/please-avoid-very-broad-beginners-questions-during-the-beta) and it's already one year old. So, let's move one and gather more visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange, I was never aware that people would perceive us as not allowing beginner questions.

The wording in our FAQ is phrased like that because we're trying to build a community of experts who can answer questions, but that doesn't mean they will only answer questions for other experts.

Given that [a search for the word beginner yields 83 questions](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=beginner), I'm somewhat startled that you got the feeling your questions weren't welcome. Especially since it didn't stop others from doing so.

But the wording of the FAQ probably could use some improvement, what would you suggest it would have to be changed to?

Comment: "Fitness professionals, experts, and enthusiasts," sounds like a good line. Some of those terms come from the wording when you commit to a proposal on Area 51.

Comment: @MattChan I like that line. professionals & trainers could be seen as redundant, but enthusiasts fits perfectly with our (presumably) largest userbase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding FAQ I think the mentioned line then should be extended to following: `Fitness - Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes, trainers and enthusiasts.` What do you think?

Comment: I'd never thought about the wording of it either, but it makes sense that we should change it. I'll cast my vote for the change to be worded as @VasiliyBorovyak has it here (professionals, athletes, trainers, and enthusiasts). I don't think professionals & trainers is redundant, as a professional runner is not the same as a running coach.