# Why has the 'Exercises for a programmer' question never been closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

[**Exercises for a programmer sitting by the PC all day**](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6/3941)

Why has this question never been closed?
It is far too broad, highly unspecific, there is no way to reasonably answer this question. It has some good answers but a lot of answers that are not useful.  Actually assessing the value of the answers isn't really possible as the scope is too broad.

This is the highest rated question and the sixth that has been asked on this site.
Is this the reason why the question hasn't been closed?

Comment: To clarify: Although I voted to close that question some weeks ago, this meta question is not an attempt to get the question closed, but to understand why people think the question should be left open.

Comment: Obviously because I'm waiting to get 100 upvotes on my answer :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be closed too at this point, but it has probably gone unnoticed for so long that people forgot about it.

Fitness is almost two years old now. There were a lot of scope changes/discussion in the first few months, but this type question never really came up although [Robert Cartaino did advise](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/please-avoid-very-broad-beginners-questions-during-the-beta) not to post this type of question. It was really one of the first questions posted to the site when it launched.

My recommendation for this question is to close it as "Not Constructive" and place a historical lock.

Comment: I agree... It's not constructive any more, but definitely worth keeping around.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 thoughts on this question:  It targets a key population of users to this site.  Its keywords "Execises for a programmer" comes up number 1 on Google, Yahoo and Bing search engines.

Comment: I think thats a good reason why the question deserves a historical lock, but not enough to leave it open.

Comment: And it has +21K views..